# Possible to subset pandas dataframe with a numpy matrix, or only other dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I subset a pandas dataframe by a boolean matrix of the same shape so that all values with corresponding false cells in the boolean matrix will appear as NA's:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)), index=['a','b','c'])
b = np.ones((3,3), dtype=bool)
b[1,1] = False

# gives 9x3 array
df[b]
```

Is there any way to do this without first converting the matrix to a pandas dataframe that has the same index and columns as the df?

On my machine, I get the following, using pandas 1.3.1 and numpy 1.21.1

```
df[b]
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
1  3  4  5
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
2  6  7  8
2  6  7  8
```

Note that

```
df.mul(b)
```

will not yield the desired outcome, since I want nulls to appear in the cells for those values that are false in the boolean matrix, not 0.

Comment: Don't use builtin as variable name (bool), please

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided works, but you convert the first array to a dataframe. (details and picture at the end.)

Note here that b acts as index and is not conerted to a DataFrame imho. Also, note you could do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)), index=['a','b','c'])
print(df)
print('----------------')
b = np.ones((3,3), dtype=bool)
print(b)
print('----------------')
b[1,1] = False
df[~b]=np.nan
print(np.where(b,df.values,np.nan)) #here the .values can be omited...
```

gives:

```
   0  1  2
a  0  1  2
b  3  4  5
c  6  7  8
----------------
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
----------------
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 3. nan  5.]
 [ 6.  7.  8.]]
```

If your question is why df needs to be converted to a dataframe, this hapens because np.nan is not an int and you are trying to assign it to an int numpy array... Converting to dataframe solves this but you could also explicitly convert to floats with e.g.

```
import numpy as np

vals = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)).astype(float)
print(vals)
print('----------------')
b = np.ones((3,3), dtype=bool)
b[1,1] = False
print(b)
print('----------------')
vals[~b]=np.nan
print(vals)
```

Which gives

```
[[0. 1. 2.]
 [3. 4. 5.]
 [6. 7. 8.]]
----------------
[[ True  True  True]
 [ True False  True]
 [ True  True  True]]
----------------
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 3. nan  5.]
 [ 6.  7.  8.]]
```

proof your code also works, **note which numbers are becomming float ;)** :
[image]

Comment: My question is why `b` needs to be converted to a dataframe, not `df`.  I understand that `df[~b] = np.NaN` works.  My question is why can't we just subset `df[b]` to get the desired outcome, since they are the same dimensions.  It's fine if the answer is 'that's just the way it is'.

Comment: b is not converted to a dataframe unless im missing something... b is used for indexing and  df[b] is just a subset of df, so e.g. in your case `df[~b]` is basically saying something like `df.iloc[(1,1)]=np.nan`.  Can you give an example of what you would like to provide, a gap and then the result you would get?

Comment: Ah I may understand your question a bit better now, added a solution based on `numpy.where` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: So I like the `np.where` solution.  However, my question still stands - it's not why df needs to be a dataframe.  It's why in order to just subset it like this - `df[b]`, we need to convert `b` to a dataframe with the same indices and columns as `df`?